# Where in GCP can I find automatic update- and maintanance-logs done on a GKE Cluster?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

We had an issue caused by an automatic update or manintanance of some sort in our GKE clusters.

I'm trying to find the logs or events that triggered and describe the update, but I'm having problems navigating the site.

Where can I find these types of logs?

Comment: [Check upgrade logs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-upgrades#check-update-log)

Comment: Thanks, seems like it was `UPGRADE_NODES` that caused this. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it was of help.

Comment: @NorwegianClassic Seems like your issue has been resolved. Can you please post the resolution steps you had done as an answer for the greater visibility of the community

Comment: @DazWilkin can I see what the upgrade did using this? Like what the new and old k8s version var etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks DazWilkin!

This was the query I used in Google Logs Explorer:

```
protoPayload.metadata.operationType=~"(UPDATE_CLUSTER|UPGRADE_MASTER)"
```

Read more about cluster and node updates [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-upgrades#check-update-log).